# dynamically create date for previous sunday at 12:00 AM

Tags: ios, nsdate

I'm struggling to figure out how to dynamically create a date object for the most previous sunday at 12:00 AM

I was thinking I could get today's date and then subtract the current day of the week + 1 at which point I could just subtract the time of the day do get down to 12AM.

so far I have the current day of the week:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
int weekday = [comps weekday];
```

at which point I can get today's date and subtract the difference of `weekday` * seconds in a day. However, how can I get today's time in seconds ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to manually calculate seconds (which is dangerous anyway because of daylight saving etc.). The following should do exactly what you want:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]]; // force US locale, because other countries (e.g. the rest of the world) might use different weekday numbering

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

[nowComponents setWeekday:1]; //Sunday
[nowComponents setHour:0]; // 12:00 AM = midnight (12:00 PM would be 12)
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *previousSunday = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

Comment: I think it's okay because 12AM is actually 0 hours (not 12). The only other thing I added was `setTimeZone` and it's looking like this will work. I've just got to run a few more tests..

Comment: FYI - this solution is not locale aware.  If the current locale is in German, for example, this will actually get the following Sunday, not the previous Sunday.  Better to use `[nowComponents setWeekday:[calendar firstWeekday]`, which will give you Sunday, Monday, or whatever the first day of the locale's week is.  If you desperately need to use Sunday rather than the culturally appropriate first day of the week, probably best to force the locale to en-US.

Comment: @Mike You're absolutely right; I've modified the code accordingly. I really wish the world would conform to ISO 8601...  http://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: Since iOS8 it seems you need to add .WeekOfMonth, to the component's flag in order to work, and I'll reply with the swift 2.0 version in case anyone needs it:

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave worrying about transitions between daylight savings time to you:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"date %@", date);

NSDateComponents *componentsToday = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date]; // NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | 
NSInteger days = componentsToday.weekday - 1;
NSLog(@"Days=%d", days);

NSDate *lastSunday = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-days*60*60*24];
NSLog(@"lastSunday %@", lastSunday);

NSDateComponents *componentsSunday = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit  fromDate:lastSunday];
[componentsSunday setHour:0];
[componentsSunday setMinute:0];
[componentsSunday setSecond:0];
NSDate *targetDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:componentsSunday];
NSLog(@"TargetDate %@", targetDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

@AndreasLey solution in Swift 2.0:

```
  func getLastSunday() -> NSDate?
{
    let today = NSDate();
    let calendar : NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    calendar.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US") // force US locale, because other countries (e.g. the rest of the world) might use different weekday numbering

    let flags : NSCalendarUnit = [.Year , .Month, .Weekday, .WeekOfMonth, .Minute , .Second]
    let nowComponents = calendar.components(flags, fromDate: today)

    nowComponents.weekday = 1 //Sunday
    nowComponents.hour = 0  // 12:00 AM = midnight (12:00 PM would be 12)
    nowComponents.minute = 0
    nowComponents.second = 0;


    let  previousSunday = calendar.dateFromComponents(nowComponents);
    return previousSunday
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is setting 12:00 am in your selected date from UIDatePicker.

```
 NSDate *oldDateSelected = datePicker.date;
 unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:oldDateSelected];
    comps.hour   = 00;
    comps.minute = 00;
    comps.second = 44;
    NSDate *newDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    return newDate;
```