# iOS calculate date stamp for last Sunday noon in UTC

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need a date stamp that refers to last Sunday noon in UTC. I got something very close from [dynamically create date for previous sunday at 12:00 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565018/dynamically-create-date-for-last-sunday-at-1200-am)  :

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

[nowComponents setWeekday:1]; //Sunday
[nowComponents setHour:12]; // noon
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];

NSDate *previousSunday = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

But this gives me the `NSDate` object for "noon in current time zone", which often does not match "noon in GTM/UTC". How can I correct this date to account for the timezones?

Comment: Do you need setTimeZone method? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Why do you think that `previousSunday` is in your time zone?

Comment: When I do `NSLog` on the `previousSunday` object in my question, I get `2013-02-03 17:00:00 +0000` - which is noon in my time zone (EST) - but clearly 5pm in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [nowComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

Comment: All `NSDate` values are referenced to UTC: "the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT." GMT == UTC.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick! While it's true that NSDate is inherently in UTC, it is not true for all the other date and time related objects.

Answer (score 0):

The date *is* UTC, the issue is that NSLog() of a date will display the date/time in your current timezone.

For the actual time use:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```