# How to convert iPhone time into seconds?

Tags: iphone, date, time, sdk

I have a problem. Before I explain, let me get a few things out of the way. I have a progress bar that has 604,800 states to become full. That is how many seconds are in a week, and every second that passes, I want the progress bar to change up one. With me?

Okay, here is my problem. Since my homemade progress bar is in seconds, I would need to convert the iPhone time into seconds and then display the progress bar accordingly. This would also reset at midnight Sunday (changeable day by the user depending on what day is the last day of the week, no difference). So for example, if it is 5 o'clock in the morning on Monday (18,000 seconds after midnight Sunday) the progress bar would be on it's 18,000th state.

How can I accomplish this? I believe I would need to first convert the [NSDate date]; into seconds and then add each second that passes to an int that resets every week.

This is really confusing, but I think I explained it well. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Read the spec for NSDate.  You can get the time value in milliseconds and do whatever arithmetic you want on it.  Also read the spec for NSDateFormatter, and see the format info [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  Also see NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`. In your case, something like:

```
NSDate *previousSunday = [self previousSunday]; // you still need to define this method.
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsFromSunday = [now timeIntervalSinceDate: previousSunday];
```

For how to implement the method `previousSunday`, check out: [dynamically create date for previous sunday at 12:00 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565018/dynamically-create-date-for-last-sunday-at-1200-am).